# Is this code a bubble sorting program?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I made a simple bubble sorting program, the code works but I do not know if its correct.

What I understand about the bubble sorting algorithm is that it checks an element and the other element beside it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    int a, b, c, d, e, smaller = 0,bigger = 0;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
    int test1[5] = { a,b,c,d,e };

    for (int test2 = 0; test2 != 5; ++test2)
    {
        for (int cntr1 = 0, cntr2 = 1; cntr2 != 5; ++cntr1,++cntr2)
        {
            if (test1[cntr1] > test1[cntr2]) /*if first is bigger than second*/{
                bigger = test1[cntr1];
                smaller = test1[cntr2];

                test1[cntr1] = smaller;  
                test1[cntr2] = bigger;
            }

        }
    }
    for (auto test69 : test1)
    {
        cout << test69 << endl;
    }
    system("pause");


}
```

Comment: Not really. you have to repeat inner loop until you did no swaps during a loop.

Comment: @serge so its like half correct?

Comment: yes) take your time to improve it

Comment: Have you tried [reading about bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)? Do the description or the pseudo-code presented in that article fit with your code? If not then no it's not bubble sort.

Comment: Try to print out during the loop the state of the array and what you are comparing/swapping. it helps you visualize what your code is doing and then you can better judge yourself if it is bubble sort or not. I learned sorting algorithms best when visualizing them

Comment: The variables `cntr1` and `cntr2` are not indepentent from each other; apparently `cntr2==cntr1+1` is an ivariant of the loop. Perhaps the question is more suitable for code review.

Comment: The main gist of Bubble sort is that after each iteration, the heaviest element lies at the end of the array.

Comment: @Hayt thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Codor No, author is not convinced this actually does what he wants it to do.

Comment: @user4581301 I am just learning the algorithm, I could put a return -1 if thats the case

Comment: @jibzoiderz forget I made that comment, and stick to one problem at a time. Get the sort done first, then worry about handling bad input.

Comment: I suggest to also add a boolean - It reduces unneeded operations.

Comment: The fifth iteration is useless as the unsorted part is reduced to a single element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bubblesort implementation.  It just is a very basic one.

Two improvements:

- the outerloop iteration may be one shorter each time since you're guaranteed that the last element of the previous iteration will be the largest.
- when no swap is done during an iteration, you're finished. (which is part of the definition of bubblesort in wikipedia)

Some comments:

- use better variable names (test2?)
- use the size of the container or the range, don't hardcode 5.
- using `std::swap()` to swap variables leads to simpler code.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9d85a7191529bc5) is a more generic example using (random access) iterators with my suggested improvements and comments and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb9eedb22229092d) with the improvement proposed by Yves Daoust (iterate up to last swap) with debug-prints

Comment: You can merge the two improvements in one: iterate until the last swap of the previous pass (if any).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I did that in my second example with a reference to your improvement.  I never thought of doing it this way before, but then, it's not often that I'm working with bubblesort.

Comment: We probably agree to say that bubblesort is not a useful algorithm in itself. But it is certainly worth the study because of these little "tricks" that can be reused in other circumstances.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: I am studying your code. I could not understand some of the libraries since I do not have enough knowledge (still at chapt 5 of c++ primer). Btw how were you able to add elements in an array?? I thought its elements are a const? EDIT: My bad, didn't see it was a vector

Comment: No problem: for the template: just replace the template code and hardcode the template parameter with std::vector<int>::iterator. utility-include: needed for std::swap, iterator-include: not needed in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The correctness of your algorithm can be explained as follows.

In the first pass (inner loop), the comparison `T[i] > T[i+1]` with a possible swap makes sure that the largest of `T[i]`, `T[i+1]` is on the right. Repeating for all pairs from left to right makes sure that in the end `T[N-1]` holds the largest element. (The fact that the array is only modified by swaps ensures that no element is lost or duplicated.)

In the second pass, by the same reasoning, the largest of the `N-1` first elements goes to `T[N-2]`, and it stays there because `T[N-1]` is larger.

More generally, in the `K`th pass, the largest of the `N-K+1` first element goes to `T[N-K]`, stays there, and the next elements are left unchanged (because they are already increasing).

Thus, after `N` passes, all elements are in place.

---

This hints a simple optimization: all elements following the last swap in a pass are in place (otherwise the swap wouldn't be the last). So you can record the position of the last swap and perform the next pass up to that location only.

Though this change doesn't seem to improve a lot, it can reduce the number of passes. Indeed by this procedure, the number of passes equals the largest displacement, i.e. the number of steps an element has to take to get to its proper place (elements too much on the right only move one position at a time).

In some configurations, this number can be small. For instance, sorting an already sorted array takes a single pass, and sorting an array with all elements swapped in pairs takes two. This is an improvement from O(N²) to O(N) !

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your code works just like Bubble Sort.

Input: 3 5 1 8 2

Output after each iteration:

```
                         3 1 5 2 8
                         1 3 2 5 8
                         1 2 3 5 8
                         1 2 3 5 8
                         1 2 3 5 8
                         1 2 3 5 8
```

Actually, in the inner loop, we don't need to go till the end of the array from the second iteration onwards because the heaviest element of the previous iteration is already at the last. But that doesn't better the time complexity much. So, you are good to go..

**Small Informal Proof:**

The idea behind your sorting algorithm is that you go though the array of values (left to right). Let's call it a pass. During the pass pairs of values are checked and swapped to be in correct order (higher right).

During first pass the maximum value will be reached. When reached, the max will be higher then value next to it, so they will be swapped. This means that max will become part of next pair in the pass. This repeats until pass is completed and max moves to the right end of the array.

During second pass the same is true for the second highest value in the array. Only difference is it will not be swapped with the max at the end. Now two most right values are correctly set.

In every next pass one value will be sorted out to the right.

There are N values and N passes. This means that after N passes all N values will be sorted like:

*{kth largest, (k-1)th largest,...... 2nd largest, largest}*

Comment: An example proves nothing.

Comment: The example shows that it is putting the heaviest element at the back of the array after each iteration. Doesn't that ring a bell??

Comment: I have nothing against illustrating the work of an algorithm with an example. But an example is insufficient for a proof.

Answer (score -1):

No it isn't. It is worse. There is no point whatsoever in the variable `cntr1`. You should be using `test1` here, and you should be referring to one of the many canonical implementations of bubblesort rather than trying to make it up for yourself.

Comment: Worse than what? The basic bubblesort algorithm states that you sort by pushing the "largest' entries to one side by swapping neighbours when needed.  Bubblesort is not known as a performant sorting algorithm.  The only improvement in wikipedia definition is the stop when no swaps were needed, which isn't a functional difference.

Comment: Also, implementing sorting algorithms is a very common exercise, it just shouldn't be used in production code.

Comment: The OP's algorithm is undisputably a Bubble Sort (admittedly with a few beginner's mistakes). The OP's is warmy invited to train on similar problems and abstain from using "black boxes" on every occasion.